# Баг в localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть код  https://plnkr.co/edit/TONJUWbsAVhuQGKg?preview который при клике на `<i class="itemAdd">#</i>` берет значение `<span class=" item_price">10</span>` и добавляет его в переменную `balance`, а после выводит переменную balance в `<p id="purse"></p>`. Ещё есть localstorage который позволяет сохранять значение переменной balance при перезагрузке страницы что он и делает , но почему-то `<p id="purse"></p>` при перезагрузке страницы берёт значение 0 хотя консоль показывает что значение переменной balance равно тому значению которое было до перезагрузки и тут происходит кульминация - если еще раз кликнуть на `<i class="itemAdd">#</i>`  то значение `<p id="purse"></p>`
сложит не 0 и значение itemPrice  а переменую balance и itemPrice.

Как сделать так чтоб после перезагрузки значение  `<p id="purse">0</p>` было не пустота ,  а значение balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let balance = +(localStorage.getItem("balance") || 0);
document.getElementById('purse').innerHTML = balance; // !!!
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".item_add"))...
```

Comment: спасибо оказалось что все проще чем мне казалось

Comment: Что тут забыл `innerHTML`?